# I want to skip the deployment of same versions of azure functions during deploying

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

While deploying, I want the pipeline to skip the same versions of azure function app. How to go ahead for this POC. Any suggestions would help.

Should I try with run once deployment? or I need to make some changes in the build code?

Comment: Are you really want to skip the same Azure Function_Extension_version?. Or Are you looking for something else?

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT Yes, I want to skip the same Azure Function_Extension version.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT Now our pipeline always overwrite version, but I want it to skip same version deploy

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a bash script task.

- Add **bash** script task to check if there is a difference using **git diff**. If there is, assign a variable to TRUE.
- While deploying, add **condition** to your job. If TRUE, let it deploy. If not, it will pass.